# How to make a file with i number of rows

Tags: fortran

I'm using this code below to generate a file with `i` number (`i=200` for instance) of rows, but the first and the second rows are fixed and I just want to create another `i` rows using a random extraction in a sphere of unitary radius in Fortran. Each row should start with m1 and then 6 random numbers between a range [0,1].

```
    program InputGen  
    implicit none 

        integer :: i,n,j
        character(len=500) :: firstLine, secondLine
        real *8 :: m1  
        real:: r(10) 

        m1=1.d0  
        firstLine='3  5   1.d-4    1.d5   0.e-3    0.0   1. 0.1 0.e0 1'  
        secondLine='4.d6 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. ' 

        call random_seed()  
        call random_number(r) 

        open(unit=100, file='INPUT.TXT',Action='write', Status='replace')
        write(100,'(A)') trim(firstLine)
        write(100,'(A)') trim(secondLine)

          do i=1,200
            write(100,'(A)') '',m1,' ',(r(n),n=1,10), 
                             ' ',(r(n),n=1,10),'0.0',&
                             ' ',(r(n),n=1,10),&
                             ' ',(r(n),n=1,10),'0.0'

          end do  

    write(*,*) 'Input file generated.'  
    write(*,*) 'Press Enter to exit...'  
    read(*,*)  

    end program InputGen
```

The first and second lines create perfectly, but the other rows in the loop not.

Comment: You ask for 6 random numbers, but I see many more. also you want to pick random points from a sphere. Is this on the surface of in the volume? And is this a 6d glome or just a 3d sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us what is wrong (how the problem exhibits), but I suspect the format is incorrect. You are just specifying `(A)`, but you have a mixed output list with strings and numbers.

You can just use a simple general format like `(*(g0))` that will apply the generic `g0` format to all items in the input list. You will want to add some manual spaces (although you already have some) in the input list to avoid joining two unrelated output items on the line.

Or you can just follow the input list and add a specific format for each item, like `(a,1x,f12.6,a,10(f12.6,1x),a ...` and so on. Adjust as needed, especially the spaces (either keep them as `' '` with the `a` descriptor, or use the `1x` descriptor.

You are also currently writing the same `r` all the time. You should generate more numbers and re-generate them an each loop iteration

```
     real:: r(40) 

     do i=1,200
        call random_number(r)

        write(100,'(*(g0))') '',m1,' ',r(1:10), 
                         ' ',r(11:20),'0.0',&
                         ' ',r(21:30),&
                         ' ',r(31:40),'0.0'

      end do
```

This does not do anything with points in a sphere or anything similar, this just prints random numbers. I hope that is clear.

Comment: ok, great. I changed the write(100,'(A)' ) to write(100,*) and it's working. :)))

Comment: You can use `write(100,*)`, but you can have your line broken at any time.

Comment: but the only problem is that each (r(n),n=1,10) produces 10 random numbers, I have to change to " (r(n),n=1,2),'0.0', (r(n),n=1,2),'0.0' " to have 6 numbers after m1. in this case, the numbers are repeatedly for all the lines!!!

Comment: what about generating different rows? because now the rows are the same just repeated 200 times!

Comment: Of course the rows are the same, you are always writing `r` from 1 to 10 and do not change `r`. You should use larger `r` and `call random_number(r)` on each `i` iteration.

Comment: Problem Solved, Thank you.

Comment: @ndee in this case, the practice on StackOverflow is to mark the answer as correct. Else, the replier does not get credit and other visitors will not know that the issue you had was ultimately resolved.